# Access SQL Subquery Criteria based on Next Record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column of QualityCheckTimes.  I also have a different table with the StartTimes and EndTimes of ProductionSkids.

I need a query that returns for each QualityCheckTime, the minimum SkidID and maximum SkidID based on their StartTimes and EndTimes.

**Sample Data**

```
 QCCheckTimes  
     12:00 AM  
      1:00 AM  
      2:00 AM  

 SkidID   SkidStartTime  SkidEndTime  
      1        12:05 AM     12:20 AM  
      2        12:21 AM     12:40 AM  
      3        12:41 AM     12:50 AM  
      4        12:51 AM      1:06 AM
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 QCCheckTimes MinSkidID  MaxSkidID 
     12:00 AM     Skid1      Skid3   
      1:00 AM     Skid4        ...  
      2:00 AM       ...
```

I've tried a few things, but the crux of it is that I need to find a way to get all the matching Skid Times between two QualityCheck times, with those QualityTimes being on separate rows.

```
SELECT...
WHERE [SkidStartDateTime] >= [QualitySamples_tbl].[SampleDateTime]
AND [SkidEndDateTime] < NEXT?? [QualitySamples_tbl].[SampleDateTime]);
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries and `Hour()` function to achieve this.

Try this:

- **table1** contains: QCCheckTimes
- **table2** Contains: SkidID,SkidStartTime,SkidEndTime

Code:

```
SELECT table1.qcchecktimes, 
       Iif([minofid] IS NULL, "...", "skid" & [minofid])  AS MinSkidID, 
       Iif([c].[maxofid] = [b].[minofid], "...", 
       Iif([maxofid] IS NULL, "...", "skid" & [maxofid])) AS MaxSkidID 
FROM   (table1 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT table1.qcchecktimes, 
                          Min(table2.skidid) AS MinOfID 
                   FROM   table1, 
                          table2 
                   WHERE  (( ( Hour([skidendtime]) ) = Hour([qcchecktimes]) )) 
                   GROUP  BY table1.qcchecktimes) AS b 
               ON table1.qcchecktimes = b.qcchecktimes) 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT table1.qcchecktimes, 
                         Max(table2.skidid) AS MaxOfid 
                  FROM   table1, 
                         table2 
                  WHERE  (( ( Hour([skidendtime]) ) = Hour([qcchecktimes]) )) 
                  GROUP  BY table1.qcchecktimes) AS c 
              ON table1.qcchecktimes = c.qcchecktimes 
GROUP  BY table1.qcchecktimes, 
          Iif([minofid] IS NULL, "...", "skid" & [minofid]), 
          Iif([c].[maxofid] = [b].[minofid], "...", 
          Iif([maxofid] IS NULL, "...", "skid" & [maxofid]));
```

Comment: Ok wow - thanks.   This looks great but intimidating.  Is [minofid] and [maxofid] functions?

Comment: no minofid and maxofid are not functions. min of skidid is getting calculated in first sub query at "Min(table2.skidid) AS MinOfID" and max of id is getting calculated in second sub query "Max(table2.skidid) AS MaxOfid "

Comment: @Kashif Qureshi, why use old style implicit joins rather than explicit?

Comment: I was getting error when using joins on expression in Access. I think Access  doesn't support joins on expression

Comment: @KashifQureshi  Ok I'm getting some output, but it looks pretty weird.  The MinId is much lower than it should be, while the MaxID is closer but still a bit off, and I'm getting some duplicates.  But I really appreciate the suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use access but in SQL Server you have two functions to achieve this query *LAG* and *LEAD*, previous and next row, you can see a tutorial here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/lag-and-lead-functions-in-sql-server/

so in SQL you can do something like this (this example is using integers not time)

```
  ----------------your single table-----------------
  declare @a table(id int)
  insert into @a
  select 1 union
  select 5 union
select 10 union
select 14 union
select 17 union
select 20 
----------------table with ranges-----------------
declare @b table (start int, finish int)
insert into @b
select 1,4 union
select 2,5 union
select 5,8 union
select 10,15 
----------------Aux Table--------------------------
declare @a_PlusNext table (id int, idNext int)
insert into @a_PlusNext
SELECT id,LEAD(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) nextId from @A

----------------------Final Query------------------
SELECT 
*
FROM @a_PlusNext
INNER JOIN @b on start >= id and finish <= idNext
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately it looks like Access SQL 2016 does not have Lag / Lead capability